# Undefined reference to std::condition_variable::notify_one GLIBCXX_3.4.11

Tags: linker, clang

I am attempting to build and link a library with Clang instead of the default GCC and I am getting the following linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/torch/csrc/autograd/engine.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt18condition_variable10notify_oneEv@@GLIBCXX_3.4.11'
```

My command is:

```
CC="clang-5.0" CXX="clang++-5.0"  LDSHARED="clang -shared" python setup.py install
```

Removing `LDSHARED` solves the problem but I need to link with `clang`, because in the full example `CFLAGS` contains flags that GCC does not recognize.

Answer (score 2):

Clang is linking by default against `libc++` (https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html) rather than `libstdc++`, which the code seems to be built against. Adding `LDFLAGS="-stdlib=libstdc++"` solves the problem.